# blender game engine, spot lamp shadow problem

Tags: game-engine, light

I have a grid mesh and a spot light above, casting checkerd shadows on the ground.
It works well in viewmode, if I render the image it works as well.

Only when I hit "p" and enter game mode, everything is just flat and more or less shadeless.

I have GLSL enabled and switched viewmode to texture before I enter the game.
Any clues?

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: See comment for solution :)

Comment: Works fine for me. Could you [upload the .blend file](http://pasteall.org/blend/) as reference?

Comment: Found the issue a moment ago: had to flip normals in order tho get the shadow in game as well. viewmode doesnt care about normal direction seems like, only bge does. pretty confusing. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can deactivate `Beackface Culling` in the material settings, then the normals should not matter anymore.